# Install an homebrew bottled binary package

Tags: macos, homebrew, travis-ci

I need to speed up a travis package generation in which I need 
    brew install fftw --with-openmp

that takes ~20 minutes to build and most of the time Travis kills my job.

My idea is to create another repo in which (once in a while) I generate the binary bottled version of `fftw --with-openmp` and then from my application repo intall that particular bottled version. I'm stuck in this last part...

I created an empty repo linked to travis (https://github.com/iltommi/fftw-openmp) in which I just have a `.travis.yml` :

```
os: osx

osx_image: xcode7.1

sudo: required

script:
 - export COMPILER=g++-6
 - brew update; brew tap homebrew/science
 - brew install --build-bottle fftw --with-openmp
 - brew bottle fftw
 - export RELEASE_FILE=$(ls fftw*bottle*.tar.gz)
 - ls -la

deploy:
  provider: releases
  edge:
    branch: releases-fix
  api_key: $github_token
  file: "${RELEASE_FILE}"
  skip_cleanup: true
  overwrite: true
```

So I get a file in the releases (https://github.com/iltommi/fftw-openmp/releases)

Now, How do I install from my other repo?
I can get it via wget but then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it has been answered here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204833/99311:

I'll leave this in case someone else need this on stackoverflow:

brew install -f fftw-3.3.5.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz

where `fftw-3.3.5.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz` is the file generated by the commands

```
brew install --build-bottle fftw --with-openmp
brew bottle fftw
```